# git, how to overwrite local changes (again)

Tags: git

There are many posts with this error, but the difference here is there is no cause for this error - nothing has been changed.

We have a branch called prod-env in devOps git.

I need to check this out locally, to see if a particular change is in it (using git log).

If I do `git checkout prod-env` I get:

```
Your branch and 'origin/prod-env' have diverged,
and have 1245 and 22 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I have no idea how this happened, as the only thing which updates this branch is a pipeline, and we never use it locally.

Someone said do `git clean` but this gives this error:

```
fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean
```

If I use `git clean -n` or `git clean -i` nothing happens - it just goes back to the prompt.  This makes no sense as if I do `git status` it tells me `and have 1245 and 22 different commits each, respectively.`

To try to figure out why git thinks something local changed I loaded it up in intellij and used its git tool, but it doesn't show any differences.

Some posts say I should do this:

- `git fetch --all` I dont want to do this as we have millions of branches
- `git branch backup-master` I dont want to do this as anything local is wrong
- `git reset --hard origin/prod-env` I dont want to do this as anything with --hard, if not 100% correct, could permanently destroy our companies source repo

Doing `git fetch --all` makes no sense.  If you are already on the branch, why not just `git fetch`?

Other posts say to do this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

Which is correct: git `reset --hard origin/prod-env` or `git reset --hard HEAD`?
Or are they the same?  why doesnt it do git fetch first if the other posts say this is required?

I found another post which says you have to do both, ie. :

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -f -d
git pull
```

if `git reset --hard` does a hard reset, why do you need to clean?

If this was svn the solution would be trivial - delete the dir and check it out again and you will now have the same as the server, with no risk of breaking anything.

Maybe the safest solution is to delete the entire repo dir, and clone again?

Comment: If you are 100% certain that you didn't do anything locally then there is no risk in resetting your local branch to the remote-tracking branch. Furthermore if you don't *care* about what you did locally anyway then there is also no risk.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The problem is that from experience, doing the wrong commands can easily cause irreversible damage.   Each post has different and apparently conflicting "solutions". e.g. some say you have to do git fetch first, some dont. Some say reset head, some say reset branch etc.

Comment: You need to do git fetch first, this command updates so called remote tracking branch, ie `origin/master`,  so you get the latest fresh version from remote server.

Comment: Re irreversible damage, you can always use `git reflog` to restore a previous state. But, easier, would be to simply copy the whole of your local repo to another directory and then run whatever commands you like on the copy -- so long as you don't run any commands that affect the remote (push, etc), you can do what you like on the copy. It's kinda klunky, but disk space is cheap, and stress is unpleasant.

Comment: `Maybe the safest solution is to delete the entire repo dir` that's certainly not safer than using `git reset --hard`.

Comment: You can always create a backup and then do whatever you want

Comment: First thing I would do is `git fetch` and then `git diff --name-status origin/prod-env`. That will give a list of all changed files. If there are some changed files, you need to figure out, which branch is the one you want. If there are no changed files, and you are happy with the history on the remote, then `git reset --hard origin/prod-env` will drop the local history in favour of the remote history, without changing any files.

Comment: The answer to "how to overwrite local changes" and how to set the state of the local `prod-env` branch to be equal to `origin/prod-env` is `git reset --hard origin/prod-env` anyway, if you like it or not.

Comment: @mkrieger1 anything local is 'safe', if I lose a day or weeks work, I can live with that, but what would be catastrophic and unsafe is breaking the remote repo in any way, e.g. by rewriting any history or deleting anything or interfering with other devs work or breaking production environemtns.

Comment: `git reset --hard` does not affect any remote repo (unless you execute it *in* the remote repo).

Comment: @mkrieger1, bad comment, regarding OPs context - branches diverged - `and have 1245 and 22 different commits each,` - he loses 22 local commits this way.

Comment: I did the following: 1) git fetch 2) git reset --hard origin/prod-env. But now when I do git status, it says I have spurious untracked files which should not be there, so there are still issues.  prod-env is a "read only" branch, whe never work on it or commit to it, or edit it in anyway

Comment: @mkrieger1 we don't know exactly what he does care, all i see is a lot of doubts.)

Comment: @mkrieger1, i misconcluded - he loses 1245 commits by doing hard reset, not 22. Just to point out.

Answer (score 0):

There are still questions about the different posted "solutions" to this issue, but the following seems to have replaced my local corrupted version with a clean checkout from origin:

```
git checkout prod-env 
(get error message)
git fetch (not git fetch --all)
git reset --hard origin/prod-env (NOT git reset --hard HEAD)
git clean -fd (this is required to get rid of spurious files which reset doesn't get rid of)
```

Comment: `git fetch -all` is okay, it does fetching from all *remotes* (usually single one - origin) not for all branches.